# Is it possible to unpack a list of tuples with a list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'd like to unpack tuples from a list of tuples into individual variables using list comprehension. E.g. how to do the second print with a list comprehension instead of an explicit loop:

```
tuples = [(2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16)]

# Print in direct order OK
print(('Squares:' + '   {} --> {}' * len(tuples)).format(
    *[v for t in tuples for v in t]))

# Print in reverse order not possible
print('Square roots:', end='')
for t in tuples:
    print ('   {} --> {}'.format(t[1], t[0]), end='')
print()

>>> Squares:   2 --> 4   3 --> 9   4 --> 16
>>> Square roots:   4 --> 2   9 --> 3   16 --> 4
```

Is it possible to replace the second print loop by a list comprehension?
Feel free to simplify further if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) `print` is a function, so you can indeed write:

```
[print ('   {} --> {}'.format(*t[::-1]), end='') for t in tuples]
```

but this is probably worse than using a `for` loop, since now you allocate memory for every iteration. In case the number of iterations is huge, you will construct a huge list filled with `None`s.

It produces:

```
>>> tuples = [(2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16)]
>>> [print ('   {} --> {}'.format(*t[::-1]), end='') for t in tuples]
   4 --> 2   9 --> 3   16 --> 4[None, None, None]
```

The `[None, None, None]` is not printed, but simply the result of the list comprehension.

But that being said, we do not need list comprehension, we can use `''.join(..)` (with a list or generator`, like:

```
print('Squares:'+''.join('   {} --> {}'.format(*t) for t in tuples))
print('Square roots:'+''.join('   {} --> {}'.format(*t[::-1]) for t in tuples))
```

this produces:

```
>>> print('Squares:'+''.join('   {} --> {}'.format(*t) for t in tuples))
Squares:   2 --> 4   3 --> 9   4 --> 16
>>> print('Square roots:'+''.join('   {} --> {}'.format(*t[::-1]) for t in tuples))
Square roots:   4 --> 2   9 --> 3   16 --> 4
```

Comment: The bit I was missing was `t[::-1]` :-) Now I see also the benefit of the generator.